# Como inserir Grid dinâmica na interface XAML do WPF

Tags: wpf, grid

Escrevi um método que cria uma Grid dinamicamente:

```
private void createMyGrid(int l, int c)
{
    //Create grid
    Grid DynamicGrid = new Grid();
    DynamicGrid.ShowGridLines = true;

    //Create lines
    for(int i=0; i<l;i++)
    {
        DynamicGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
    }

    //create columns
    for (int j = 0; j < c; j++)
    {
        DynamicGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
    }

    // Display grid into a Window
    this.Content = DynamicGrid;
```

}

A MainWindow.xaml está assim:

```
<Window x:Class="dinamicButtonBasics.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:dinamicButtonBasics"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid x:Name="mainGrid">
    <Grid x:Name="myGrid">

    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

É possível fazer com que a minha"myGrid" passe a ser a que eu criei dinamicamente?
De outra forma, como posso substituir a "myGrid" pela que é criada pela função?

Answer (score 0):

Afinal era simples ...

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    myGrid.Children.Clear();
    myGrid.Children.Add(createMyGrid(3,4));
}
```

... mas a função foi alterada assim:

```
private Grid createMyGrid(int l, int c)
{
    //Create grid
    Grid DynamicGrid = new Grid();
    DynamicGrid.ShowGridLines = true;

    //Create lines
    for(int i=0; i<l;i++)
    {
        DynamicGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
    }

    //create columns
    for (int j = 0; j < c; j++)
    {
        DynamicGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
    }

    //Add buttons ti the grid
    populateGrid(DynamicGrid);

    return DynamicGrid;
}
```